# Is there a way to ensure that a group of directories is created, without having to declare the path?

Tags: python, file, directory, path, python-3.6

I would like to check if a directory exists (and create it if not), without having to declare the directory.

```py
import os

GROUPS_MANAGERS = '/staff/Managers'
GROUPS_SALESASSOCIATE = '/staff/Salesman'
GROUPS_CASHIERS = '/staff/Cashiers'
GROUPS_STOCKERS = '/staff/Stockers'


if not os.path.isdir(): #how do i make it so it can check if ANY directory exists
    os.mkdir(GROUPS_MANAGERS) 
    os.mkdir(GROUPS_SALESASSOCIATE) 
    os.mkdir(GROUPS_CASHIERS) 
    os.mkdir(GROUPS_STOCKERS)
```

Comment: Do you want to create the directories only if none of them exist, or do you want to check and create each?

Comment: just create them if none of them exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly:

```
import os 

GROUPS_MANAGERS = '/staff/Managers'
GROUPS_SALESASSOCIATE = '/staff/Salesman'
GROUPS_CASHIERS = '/staff/Cashiers'
GROUPS_STOCKERS = '/staff/Stockers'

for p in (GROUPS_MANAGERS, GROUPS_SALESASSOCIATE, GROUPS_CASHIERS, GROUPS_STOCKERS):
    os.makedirs(p, exist_ok=True)
```

This creates each of your directories and does not produce error if any of them already existed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this question has been asked before on stackoverflow, but here you go.

Borrowed from comment by [MrBean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12480730/mrbean-bremen)

```
import os
os.makedirs('my_folder',exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: On Python 3, you can use `os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True) `

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, simple and clean. thumbs up!